# Firefox returning content-type text/html not supported for video

Tags: angular, firefox, video, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to get video from the server to play on the frontend.

Currently, I am working on a project that user an Angular 4 frontend and a Rails 5 API backend. The goal is to upload video to the backend for streaming on the frontend. But, the problem I ran into is Firefox saying the video has the wrong content-type.

```
HTTP “Content-Type” of “text/html” is not supported. Load of media resource http://localhost:4200/ failed.  1)
All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.  1)
Cannot play media. No decoders for requested formats: text/html
```

So, I did some reading and troubleshooting and came to the conclusion that the problem must be in backend, so i added a mime type to rails and explicitly added the content type. Here's the relevant backend code.

Movies Controller
    class MoviesController < ApplicationController
        def index
            @movies = Movie.all

```
        render json: @movies, status: 200
    end

    def create
        movie = Movie.new(movie_params)

        if movie.save
            render json: movie, status: 201
        else
            render json: { errors: movie.errors }, status: 422
        end
    end

    def update
        movie = Movie.find(params[:id])

        if movie.update_attributes(movie_params)
            render json: movie, status: 200
        else
            render json: { errors: movie.errors }, status: 422
        end
    end

    def show
        movie = Movie.find(params[:id])

        render json: movie, status: 200, mime_type: Mime::Type.parse("video/mp4"), 
                                                                        content_type: "video/mp4"
    end

    private

        def movie_params
            params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :year, :plot, :video)
        end
end
```

mime_types.rb

```
Mime::Type.register "video/mp4", :mp4
```

model

```
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
    has_attached_file :video, styles: {
        medium: { 
            geometry: "640x480", 
            format: 'mp4' }
    }, processors: [:transcoder]
    validates_attachment :video, presence: true
    do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :video
end
```

After making these changes i tested with a curl command and got the following output.

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 29 Oct 2017 17:04:03 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Location: http://localhost
Expires: Sun, 29 Oct 2017 17:04:02 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache

<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: video/mp4; charset=utf-8
ETag: W/"a8c0ff616394ec492839299f528b046c"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
X-Request-Id: 01c9df7d-b878-4ea1-91a3-e22124d73d0c
X-Runtime: 0.022902
Vary: Origin
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{"id":1,"title":"Test","plot":"Awesomeness","year":1977,"created_at":"2017-10-28T04:39:35.981Z","updated_at":"2017-10-28T04:39:35.981Z","video_file_name":"SampleVideo_720x480_1mb.mp4","video_content_type":"video/mp4","video_file_size":1057149,"video_updated_at":"2017-10-28T04:39:04.001Z"}
```

This output has 2 content types. I am assuming one is for submission and the other is for receiving. The first one has a content-type of text/html while the second has video/mp4. So, I checked Firefox again still had the same error and the video still not loading.

Here is some relevant code from the Angular frontend insight if it is needed.

service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from "@angular/http"
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
import { Movie } from './dvd'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
// import { Movies } from './mock-dvd'

@Injectable()
export class DvdService {
  moviesURL = 'http://localhost:3001/movies'

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getMovies(): Observable<Movie[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.moviesURL)
        .map((res: Response) => <Movie[]>res.json())
  }

  getMovie(id: number): Observable<Movie> {
    return this.http.get(this.moviesURL + '/' + id + '.json')
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  }
}
```

component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router, ParamMap } from '@angular/router'
import { Location } from '@angular/common'
import { DvdService } from '../../dvd.service'
import { Movie } from '../../dvd'

import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap'  

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dvd-item',
  templateUrl: './dvd-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dvd-item.component.scss']
})
export class DvdItemComponent implements OnInit {
  movie: Movie
  id: number

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private location: Location,
              private router: Router,
              private dvdService: DvdService) { 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap
      .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.dvdService.getMovie(+params.get('id')))
      .subscribe(movie => this.movie = movie);
  }
}
```

template

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <div *ngIf="movie">
                <h6>{{ movie.title }}</h6>
                <h6>{{ movie.video_file_name }}</h6>

                <video width="640" height="480">
                    <source src="{{ movie.video }}" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you getting 301, i cant find the server side logic for that, also what all requests are you sending? all network calls?

Comment: The 301 is from an in my angular app-routing file that i am still trying to get a handle on. As for the request i think you me the curl request which was: curl -v -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -H "Accept: application/json" -F "movie[title]=Test" -F "movie[year]=1977" -F "movie[plot]=Awesomeness" -F "movie[video]=@/home/linuxbox/Desktop/SampleVideo_720x480_1mb.mp4" http://localhost:3001/movies

Comment: Ah, one problem that I see is the accept header, if you are expecting the movie in chunks , the accept header should not be json,it should be appropriate mime type. can you change that and post the result

Comment: Here a gist of a new submission with the accept header changed. I still get the same errors in firefox: https://gist.github.com/nix12/1d553c59b26f67777ece682e02e05b3f